# Is the movie Bright based on a book?

Tags: bright-2017

**Is the movie [Bright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bright_(film)) based on a book?**

Wikipedia doesn't mention one, so probably not, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Everything suggests no. I don't know how you want us to give you canonical evidence, but given this [/r/fantasy thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/6ptx08/book_or_series_similar_to_the_upcoming_movie/) doesn't mention a novel I'm going to assume it wasn't a book. Book recommendations are off-topic, I'm closing this question as such.

Comment: Is this movie as bad as it sounds? I mean, I'm getting _Theodore Rex_ vibes here.

Comment: @MrLister It's not quite as bad. It's not even Amazing Spiderman 2 bad. But it's bad. I almost recommend watching it if you are into that sort of thing (bad movies, not bad fantasy), but the most entertainingly bad parts are things like "someone selected the wrong brackground music for that scene", it might not be enough to justify the 2 hours it takes to get through this mess

Comment: @Edlothiad Ok, sorry. It's ok to edit out the recommendation question, it was clearly in the wrong place, but why not keep the main one? I figured that since it's a fantasy movie, this would be the right place to ask about it.

Comment: The recommendation has been edited out, I'd voted to close before it's removal. As has at least a few of the others. It should be re-opened if it enters the queue. The other question is fine here. This is the right place to ask. But people may still judge it to be a poor question.

Comment: @MrLister I enjoyed it.  You really can't go by what other peolpe say if you like action films with fantasy give it a go.  You can always turn it off ;)

Comment: I mean... yes and no. No not any one particular book but yes it's clearly influenced by Shadowrun. Which is itself Gibson's stuff with trolls.

Comment: @MrLister My partner and I greatly enjoyed *Bright*.  For what it is (buddy cop movie w/ elves and orcs and magic) it's pretty well done and the action is sufficient to carry past the questions like "how did X occur in a world where Christianity ought to have been replaced w/ something connected to an internal event?" (no spoilers)

Comment: While I agree with the statement that it was not directly based off of a book, I'd add Alex P. Berg's *[Daggers and Steele](http://alexpberg.com/daggers-steele/)* books to the list of possible influences, being a police drama set in a world much like our own but with fantastic elements that have always been present in the world. The chief difference being that in Berg's world, there are no firearms, but bladed weapons are treated much like how firearms are in our world, restricted and licensed.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks for that, I was just thinking how Bright styled book would probably be great to read. I have to check those out!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No, Bright is not based on any book.

Bright is an original work in the sense that it is not an adaptation of a novel with a similar name or premise such as *[Blade Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner)* and *[Do Androids Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F)*, *[The Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings)* and *[The Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_(film_series))* or *[Arrival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrival_(film))* and *[Story of your Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Your_Life)*.

It's an original script, written by Max Landis, which then went through a studio bidding war, before Netflix won the rights.

> Written as a "spec" script by brash, social media-loving screenwriter phenom Max Landis, Bright sparked a movie studio bidding war last March before selling to Netflix for $4 million (with an overall $90 million production commitment by the streaming service
>   <sub>[What Is Will Smith's New Netflix Movie, Bright?](https://www.gq.com/story/will-smith-netflix-movie-bright-max-landis)</sub>

Landis set it in a typical fantasy world:

> "It's a fantasy film," Landis said, between sips of a mojito. "Dungeons and Dragons, Lord of the Rings, Warcraft, Game of Thrones—it's that type of world, American mythic archetypal fantasy. But it takes place right now."
>
> "Those worlds, whatever they may have been, were biblical times," he continued. "Everyone knows there was a dark lord and he rose and he fell and all the races united. Now you're you, I'm me, that woman over there is a centaur and it's not a big deal. They're not a big percentage of the population, there's word of them becoming rarer and rarer and getting all sorts of hereditary diseases. But you know what? Until then, there's a centaur billionaire, there's a centaur CEO. Everyone knows orcs. Everyone knows goblins. Everyone knows elves and dwarves. All of these various races that live among us."
>   <sub>[ibid.](https://www.gq.com/story/will-smith-netflix-movie-bright-max-landis)</sub>

It has been heavily marketed as a Netflix original, and while it may be inspired by various pieces of fantasy and "buddy cop" films, it is an original written by Max Landis.

---

As for the recommendation of a novel (which is hidden) [@Broklynite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/24024/broklynite) and two users on reddit suggest Shadowrun.

> I mean... yes and no. No not any one particular book but yes it's clearly influenced by Shadowrun. Which is itself Gibson's stuff with trolls
>   <sub>[Comment by Broklynite under question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179321/is-the-movie-bright-based-on-a-book#comment484349_179321)</sub>
>
> It's downright suspicious how similar the world in that trailer is to the Shadowrun RPG setting. Shadowrun has a whole lot of tie-in novels, but from what I understand most of them are at a 'fun if dumb read' at best, like most tie-in fiction.
>   I would suggest, and highly recommend, buying yourself the Shadowrun Dragonfall (and if you enjoy that one Shadowrun Hong Kong. Skip Shadowrun Returns) video game.
>   <sub>[Comment by /u/RouserVoko](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/6ptx08/book_or_series_similar_to_the_upcoming_movie/dks9q75/) on [this /r/fantasy thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/6ptx08/book_or_series_similar_to_the_upcoming_movie/)</sub>

Comment: Notable difference is that the Shadowrun world *changed* at some point in modern time (late 20th or early 21st century).  Internally, it's clear that there have been elves, orcs, etc. in the *Bright* world for at least 2000 years, likely for as long as there have been humans (if not longer).

Comment: Yes, I was going to add differences, but having not been in contact with either, I thought it would be a more difficult thing to weed out from Wikipedia and the like.

Comment: Urban fantasy is nothing new, nor is setting a buddy-buddy cop movie in an urban fantasy world.

Comment: @Valorum did I ever say it was new?

Comment: I would say that similarities with Shadowrun are extremely superficial. Shadowrun is after all about cyberpunk meets high fantasy world.

Comment: To me Bright felt like what-if urban fantasy movie -- a speculation what happens when "The Lord of the Rings" world reaches technologically to the point where we are right now. Sure, there are differences, but core stuff is all there -- one additional step and Tolkien Estate would send a Cease and Desist letter.

Comment: "Any other book" Other? Bright is not a book; what do you mean by "other" in your first sentence? Also "written together by Max Landis" together with whom? Or do you mean written together as in "put together"?

Comment: I mean sure, @TylerH, if you're wanting to be pedantic, I should remove the word other. However when I'd written the title my train of thought was already on the list of films/series that had been adaptations and therefore use the word other. Books other than the 3 examples provided (as it's obviously not an adaptation of those 3). I think it's _abundantly_ clear I don't think Bright is a book. In the same vein, together should not be in the post, as it's clearly out of place. You're welcome to suggest edits when you see glaring errors. They are recommended.

Comment: @Edlothiad I am not complaining, I'm only asking for clarification, because it confused me (so, it's probably not *abundantly* clear). Also, when seeking clarification, users should leave a comment, not make assumptions and suggest an edit that potentially alters the OP's meaning or intent.

Comment: Not quite what Mr Landis is smoking here "American mythic archetypal fantasy" huh dnd is European medieval fantasy!

Comment: @Neuromancer ASOIAF and LotR are based on European medieval fantasy or pre european medieval fantasy. I believe he's associating the mythic, archetypal fantasy of those works with his chosen american setting, not calling the works he listed _American_ archetypal fantasy.

Answer (score 6):

According to the film's director, the show was a collaborative creation based on an *original script* (e.g. **not one based on a pre-existing work**) written by Max Landis.

> **Q. In Suicide Squad you had the comic book world to base that movie’s vision on. With Bright were you free to create from scratch?**
>
> **Ayer:** *Yeah. **It came from a script Max Landis wrote kind of as an homage to me and my cop movies, then adding these incredible elements.** So in a
>   lot of ways, you’re working from reality as a baseline and then the
>   other side of it is how do you take these incredible elements and then
>   ground them and make them feel part of our reality?*
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Bright’ Director David Ayer on Creating a Fantasy L.A. for Netflix [Interview]](http://www.slashfilm.com/bright-director-interview/)</sup></sub>

Landis himself describes his inspiration behind the fantasy elements as being *"[mainstream Western-fantasy"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HighFantasy)* tropes from the likes of Dungeons & Dragons and Lord of the Rings mixed with the sort of [gritty cop films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Ayer#Filmography) that David Ayers typically produces.

> *"Bright is kinda hard to explain, because it's so simple. **Basically,
>   Dungeons and & Dragons, Lord of the Rings, mainstream Western-fantasy,
>   right? Elves, orcs, dragons. Warcraft does this, so many things do
>   this...That was biblical times.** So, that all happened, a version of
>   that. The quest, the RPG world happened. And then, thousands of years
>   passed and things slowly evened out and we finally got to a point
>   where you're Stephen, I'm Max and the camera-guy's an orc and it's not
>   a big deal."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Watch: Max Landis Hopes ‘Bright’ Will Be His ‘Star Wars’](http://collider.com/max-landis-bright-star-wars-interview/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

No, the movie is not based on a book, but it's definitely influenced by several. If I had to pick three most obvious sources, I would choose J.R.R.Tolkiens "The Lord of the Ring" Middle-earth stuff, Jim Butchers "The Dresden Files" (urban fantasy detective stuff / dark humor) and AD&D because of its general vibe.

Couple of examples. Here's a piece from this interview: ([From GQ](https://www.gq.com/story/will-smith-netflix-movie-bright-max-landis))

> "It's a fantasy film," Landis said, between sips of a mojito. "Dungeons and Dragons, Lord of the Rings, Warcraft, Game of Thrones—it's that type of world, American mythic archetypal fantasy. But it takes place right now."

Later he says:

> "Everyone knows orcs. Everyone knows goblins. Everyone knows elves and dwarves. All of these various races that live among us."

Basically he gives you some references and if you are familiar with at least some of those you're off to a good start -- the movie does not make much effort to explain what is going on. It expects you to be familiar with the material its derived of.

And don't forget the movie tagline: "The Lord of the Rings meets Training Day": ([From Geekfeed](https://www.geekfeed.com/new-bright-pictures/))

> Smith tells EW that Bright is like Training Day meets The Lord of the Rings, which the pictures would attest to, and frankly, we’re down with that kind of mash-up.

Similarities with Dresdenverse are my own impression, because the whole movie feels like a typical end battle straight out from any book from Dresden Files series.

Comment: Maker of this movie have been pointing out D&D and LotR influences almost every interview they had. I'll update the original asnwer with some references.

Comment: A very substantial improvement. You have my +1 and a pat on the back for making the effort.

Comment: Can you offer any proof of the connection between this and Dresden files?

Comment: I already mentioned that it's my own impression not explicitly mentioned anywhere, intentionally left there for people who want to read something similar. Actually Reddit is full of discussions covering this topic. Some people seem to think that there are strong similarities with Shadowrun as well, but being familiar with all three I disagree. Shadowrun takes place is a cyberpunk world while Dresdenverse is an urban fantasy similar to Bright.

Answer (score -5):

Most definitely. The movie is based on 'Thud' by Terry Pratchett. Trolls have been replaced by orcs, elves have replaced dwarves and the Will Smith character is a very credible Vimes.

Comment: Okay, but how do you know?

Comment: It's hard to see the connection between a movie set in what looks recognizably like present-day Earth, and a book that takes place on Discworld. Also, I'm not under the impression that the movie in question was (intentional) comedic in nature. Can you explain what leads you to believe *Bright* was deliberately plagiarizing *Thud* (given that the writer of the original screenplay claims the work was original from him, albeit influenced by any number of genre works)?